# ASP.NET Textbox: Display value in telephone format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox (`txtPhone`). When my web page loads, I set the value of `txtPhone.Text`. How can I make sure that this value is displayed in the following format: `000-0000-000`?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the needed format to the `ToString` function..

```
txtPhone.Text = phoneValue.ToString("000-0000-000");
```